# How to identify pushback under Win IOCP?

Tags: tcp, iocp

How can I identify TCP pushback when using IOCP? I.e. how can I find out that the receiver is not receiving, that tx/rx buffers on both sides of connection are full and that the sender should cease to send more data?

Comment: Why do you want to know? It's not like your sends start failing when the buffers become full. Just send at full throttle.

Comment: One reason that you might want to know is that TCP pushback is a valid form of TCP flow control which requires no protocol level support in your application level protocol. So you may need to know simply because your clients expect to be able to use it. Also, if you just ignore pushback and continue to send then you're opening your self up to serious denial of service attacks which could use up an uncontrollable amount of non-paged pool memory on the sender and this could, in some circumstances, crash the box. See the link in my answer for how/why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With any async TCP send operation the way to determine the rate that the peer is receiving data is to monitor the rate of send completions on the sender.

I've written about this in depth [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/06/tcp-flow-control-and-asynchronous-writes.html). In summary, when the receiver's buffers fill and TCP flow control is in operation and the TCP window is reduced the sender cannot send which causes the sender's TCP buffers to fill. This then means that async send requests can not complete. If you track the number of outstanding send requests that are pending you can spot this situation and throttle the sender.

Answer (score 2):

When this happens, the send won't complete.

Comment: The problem being that second send is done in async way even though there is still space in the tx buffer. That being the case how can I disinguish "second send" from "TCP pushback" scenario?

Comment: You can distinguish by the rate at which sends complete. If the buffers aren't full, there's no pushback. Once the buffers are full, sends will complete at the same rate as space is made in the buffers, which will be the same as the rate at which the receiver is receiving.